# 2x Simplex optic fiber patch cord vs. Duplex

Tags: optical-cable

I need to connect a patch panel (SC) to a Switch (LC) with a HP X121 1G SFP LC LX Transceiver. In theory I should use a 10m Duplex patch cord SC-LC Single mode, but I only have 10m Simplex at the moment, so I was thinking to use two Simplex cables instead of the Duplex.

Testing it physically is a bit complicated, so I wanted to know if it's fine in principle. TBH I dont see why it shouldnt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplex (i.e: 2x fibres) carries data in one direction for each fibre.

Simplex (i.e: 1x fibre) is either one of a pair, or uses [Wavelength-division multiplexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelength-division_multiplexing) to achieve a two-way link...

So one Simplex fibre won't do the job... but two Simplex of similar lengths might / should! Have you tried it?

Comment: Attie hi, no I havent tried it yet. I have to make sure before going with this idea

Comment: Yes it's confirmed. I tried it and it works.